# Excel-friendly html: keeping a list inside a single cell

Tags: html, css, excel, html-lists

I know that when generating html that needs to be viewed in Excel, if I want to ensure that `<br>` tags don't cause a new row to be generated, I can specify

```
<style><!--table br {mso-data-placement:same-cell;} --></style>
```

In the `<head>` section.

What do I need to do if I want the same behaviour for lists (i.e. for content inside of `<ul>` or `<ol>` sections to be contained in the same cell)?

Comment: NB: Don't put the styles in comments.

Comment: Copy the css, and change 'table br' to 'ul br' I would think.

Comment: Somewhere a fuzzy bunny is beaten every time an MSO-object is used....There are rendering engines that will properly export Excel documents in a manner that's clean, proper, and native.  My tool of choice is PHPExcel (http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/), but it's just one of several options

Answer (score 2):

As many of you probably know, you can output data (a report, for example) as an Excel file, simply by adding right content-type and content-disposition header:

Response.ContentType = “application/vnd.ms-excel“;

Response.AppendHeader(“content-disposition“, “inline; filename=report.xls“);

add into a stylesheet:

br {mso-data-placement:same-cell;}