# VBA - Paste Multiple Lines of HTML into Single Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I used another answer on SO to be able to convert an HTML string to displayed rich text in excel.

However, it comes with a nasty side effect of not being able to add data for multiple lines in a single cell (recommendation I found was to remove the paste logic).

Ideally, I'd like to NOT use the CreateObject for Internet Explorer in my solution, and just get the paste to work properly.

Here's the code that is found using a dictionary that does the paste to each cell.

How do I accomplish both the conversion of an HTML string to text AND paste multiple lines to a single cell?

```
            ' Sort By Years Descending
            Dim yearKey As Variant
            Dim firstYear As Boolean
            Dim cellData As String
            firstYear = True
            cellData = "<HTML><DIV>"
            For Each yearKey In stakeholderEvents(stakeholder).Keys

                If Not firstYear Then
                    cellData = cellData & "<DIV></DIV>" ' Add Extra Blank Line
                End If

                cellData = cellData & "<B>" & yearKey & "</B>" & "<UL>" ' Add Year


                ' Loop Through Events For Year
                Dim eventItem As Variant
                For Each eventItem In stakeholderEvents(stakeholder)(yearKey)

                    cellData = cellData & "<LI>" & eventItem & "</LI>"
                Next

                cellData = cellData & "</UL>"

                firstYear = False
            Next

            cellData = cellData & "<DIV></BODY></HTML>"

            Set clipboardData = CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
            clipboardData.SetText cellData
            clipboardData.PutInClipboard

            Sheet1.Activate

            'Sheet1.Range (Sheet1.Cells(rowIndex, stakeholderEventsColumn).Address)
            Sheet1.Cells(rowIndex, stakeholderEventsColumn).Select

            'Sheet1.Cells(rowIndex, stakeholderEventsColumn).Select
            Sheet1.PasteSpecial Format:="Unicode Text"
```

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you mean by "not being able to add data for multiple lines in a single cell".  Also it would help if you could reference the other code you're using.

Comment: Can you add sample html that is being pasted or if it contains any br or tr tags

Comment: @Slai "<HTML><DIV><B>HELLO</B><UL><LI>EVENT1</LI><LI>EVENT2</LI></UL></DIV></HTML>"

Comment: This is where RPA solutions like Automation Anywhere would be of benefit to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML alternative (reference [Excel-friendly html: keeping a list inside a single cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563680/excel-friendly-html-keeping-a-list-inside-a-single-cell)) :

```
Set clipboardData = CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
clipboardData.SetText "<table><style>br {mso-data-placement:same-cell}</style><tr><td>" _
                    & "<b>Line 1</b><br>Line 2<br>Line 3"
clipboardData.PutInClipboard
Sheet1.Range("b2").PasteSpecial
```

---

XML alternative (the XML can be adjusted by analyzing the `.Value(11)` of a formatted cell) :

```
Dim c As Range
Set c = Sheet1.Range("b2")
c.Value = vbLf
c.Value(11) = Replace(c.Value(11), "<Data ss:Type=""String"">&#10;</Data>", _
    "<ss:Data ss:Type=""String"" xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"">" & _
    "<B>Line 1</B>&#10;Line 2&#10;Line 3</ss:Data>")
```

Comment: ill check the html alternative tonight...in some cases i have free form html...so alternative 2 wont work

Comment: The html seems to work only with `<br>` tags and XML with `&#10;` encoded LF characters. I was thinking that they would need about the same effort to replace the html tags, but I suppose XML might be trickier as it's stricter to what it allows. Another alternative might be to [embed a WebBrowser ActiveX control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35024440/how-to-make-microsoft-web-browser-object-work-in-excel-2016), or if the html can be pasted as an image.

Comment: ill try div {mso-data-placement:same-cell} to add to style and see if that works...i can always try to replace the div tags that i have in other examples too

Comment: thank you for spending the time on this...i appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're using HTML for formatting, and Excel is always going to paste the HTML so that block-level elements go into different cells.

Another approach would be to use Excel's built-in formatting instead of using HTML tags. This will also let you eschew using the Clipboard object. Here's an example of adding some text to a range, and then formatting some of the text differently (i.e. bolding):

```
    Public Sub PopulateHtmlData()
        Dim cell As Excel.Range

        Dim s1 As String, s2 As String
        s1 = "Item 1"
        s2 = "Item 2"

        Set cell = Excel.Range("$A$1")
        ' use Chr(10) to add a new line in the cell
        cell.Value = s1 & Chr(10) & s2

        cell.Characters(0, Len(s1) - 1).Font.Bold = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: its dynamic data...so i dont know what the format will be

Comment: You just have to keep track of where each part of the string starts and stops (e.g. have a dictionary of positions in the text that need additional formatting).

Comment: i also have another cell with free form html data...so i need something more dynamic